# Can't go from a view to another after doing some instructions

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have this implementation in a part of my app:

Why when I click on "cerca per ISBN" button it goes to the tableView without doing the instructions that I have written?

This is the code of the "cerca per ISBN" button that I click:

```
@IBAction func ISBNButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {

    let libro = Libro.text! as String

    if Libro.text!.isEmpty  {

        //Alert per segnalare i campi mancanti, oltre a caselle rosse

        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Attenzione\n", message:"Inserire il codice ISBN", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in }

        myAlert.addAction(okAction);
        self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);

        // placeholder rosso se la text è vuota

        Libro.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Digita qui...", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red])

        //se tutti i campi obbligatori sono stati inseriti, proseguo ad altri controlli
    }else{
        if(isNumeric(string: libro)){
            if((libro.characters.count) < 13 || (libro.characters.count) > 13){

                //Alert per segnalare l'ISBN più corto di 13 numeri

                var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Attenzione\n", message:"L'ISBN deve essere di 13 cifre", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in }

                myAlert.addAction(okAction);
                self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
            }else{
                //inviare dati al server
                let myUrl = NSURL(string:"http://chuadiv.ddns.net/easytoschool/fetch_book_detailed.php");

                let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:myUrl as! URL);
                request.httpMethod = "POST";
                let postString = "name=\(libro)&mail=\(UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "userEmail") as? String)";
                request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
                    data, response, error in

                    if error != nil{
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }

                    var err: NSError?

                    do{
                        var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray


                        if let parseJSON: NSArray = json{

                            for index in 0...parseJSON.count-1 {

                                print("ciao")
                                let libro = parseJSON[index] as! [String:Any]
                                print("\n\n",index,":\n")

                                let book = resultCell.init(bookId: libro["id"] as! String,bookName: libro["name"] as! String,bookAuthor: libro["author"] as! String,bookSchool: libro["school"] as! String,bookPrice: libro["price"] as! String,bookStatus: libro["status"] as! String,bookISBN: libro["isbn"] as! String,bookType: libro["type"] as! String,bookIdSeller: libro["idSeller"] as! String,bookNameSeller: libro["nameSeller"] as! String,bookSurnameSeller: libro["surnameSeller"] as! String)

                                book.printBook();

                                HomeViewController.booksArray.append(book)
                            }

                        }
                    }catch{
                        print("error=\(error)")
                        return
                    }
                }
                task.resume();

                performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeToListBook", sender: self)

            }
        }else{
            var myAlert = UIAlertController(title:"Attenzione\n", message:"Inserire solo numeri per la ricerca attraverso codice ISBN", preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle.alert);

            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Ok", style:UIAlertActionStyle.default){ action in }

            myAlert.addAction(okAction);
            self.present(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil);
        }
    }
}
```

I want that when I press the button it sets my array and after it goes to the tableView, but I can't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that completion block of `dataTask` will call async so it will call later and you are currently performing segue outside the completion block of it. So what you need to do is call `performSegue` inside the completion block of `dataTask` also on `Main` thread. Also use `URL` and `URLRequest` instead of `NSURL` and `NS(Mutable)URLRequest`

```
let myUrl = URL(string:"http://chuadiv.ddns.net/easytoschool/fetch_book_detailed.php")

let request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
request.httpMethod = "POST";
let postString = "name=\(libro)&mail=\(UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "userEmail")!)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
    data, response, error in

    if error != nil{
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    var err: NSError?

    do{
        var json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String:Any]]


        if let parseJSON = json {                
            for libro in in parseJSON {                                        
                let book = resultCell.init(bookId: libro["id"] as! String,bookName: libro["name"] as! String,bookAuthor: libro["author"] as! String,bookSchool: libro["school"] as! String,bookPrice: libro["price"] as! String,bookStatus: libro["status"] as! String,bookISBN: libro["isbn"] as! String,bookType: libro["type"] as! String,bookIdSeller: libro["idSeller"] as! String,bookNameSeller: libro["nameSeller"] as! String,bookSurnameSeller: libro["surnameSeller"] as! String)

                book.printBook();

                HomeViewController.booksArray.append(book)
            }

            //Perform segue now
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeToListBook", sender: self)
            }                
        }
    }catch{
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
}
task.resume()
```

**Note:** In Swift use Swift native type array and dictionary instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`.

Comment: I have written your part of code, but it doesn't function. It goes immediately to the other view without printing the "if part"

Comment: In the other view I want to print the array set before, but it tells "index out of range"; I think it's because it goes immediately to the view without setting the array

Comment: And I have this kind of error in another part of my app

Comment: @Marco I think in storyboard you have created segue from button to destionation controller instead of From ViewController to ViewController

Comment: So I don't have to create segue fronte Button to ViewController?

Comment: @Marco Yes, Remove that segue and create from your sourceViewController to destinationViewController and then you all set to go

Comment: @Marco Have you created segue from Source ViewController to destinationViewController is it working after that?

Answer (score 0):

you are appending items to an array of another instance, or even to some static var instead of passing it

what you should do is create class of `Book` with all properties

```
class Book {
    let id: String
    init(data: [String:Any]) {
        self.id = data["id"] as? String ?? "" //or some other error handling
    }
}
```

then create an array of books inside current `UIViewController`

`var books: [Book] = []`

then do something like

```
let book = Book(data: libro)
books.append(book)
```

to pass data you should create an array of books inside destination controller (`HomeViewController`)

set its `DataSource` and `Delegate` functions to create `UITableViewCells` using this array

and pass data like

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender _: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "homeToListBook" {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? HomeViewController {
            destinationVC.books = self.books
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
and as Nirav D mentioned, segue should be called in main thread after data has been parsed, did not notice this